# spresenseのメインボードと拡張ボードの仕様について

Tags: spresense

spresenseのメインボードや拡張ボードはBluetoothに対応していますか？

Comment: お尋ねの情報はこちらで聞くよりメーカーサイト(https://www.sony-semicon.co.jp/products/smart-sensing/spresense/ )で確認する方が正確ですが、調査された上での疑問点があるのでしょうか？だとしたら、どういった点が疑問なのか詳細を記入していただいた方がアドバイスを得られやすいと思います。

Comment: Spresense はスタック・オーバーフローでの質問を推奨しており、質問場所はここでも良さそうです。ハードウェアの質問がオントピックなのかどうかはまた別に議論が必要かもしれませんが……。 https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/support/spresense-programming-support-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 2):

現時点で、メインボードおよびソニー自社製の拡張ボードは[対応していません](https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/specifications)。
ROHM社の[サードパーティー製](https://www.rohm.co.jp/support/spresense-add-on-board)拡張ボード[SPRESENSE-BLE-EVK-701](https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/spresense-add-on-boards)で対応可能です。